# Checkstyle whitespace checking

Tags: checkstyle

I have this seemingly innocent looking code.

```
String str = (String)convert.fromBytes(bytes);
```

And I get `'cast' is not followed by whitespace.` from checkstyle.
So I add a space after `(String)` and I got `')' is followed by whitespace.` ...

I've play around with the configure (and found many of them might involve this). After a while I got confused what I have changed (Hahaha) but I manage to have the warning gone for A SPACE after type cast. However, I prefer not to have space after type cast. So, can anyone tell me what exactly to set to remove the warning when I have NO SPACE after type case.

**Edit:**

Here is what I first wrote:

```
String str = (String)convert.fromBytes(bytes);
```

Then I get

`'cast' is not followed by whitespace.`.

So I changed to

```
String str = (String) convert.fromBytes(bytes);
```

then I got

`')' is followed by whitespace.`

What I want is to write the following without any warning.

```
String str = (String)convert.fromBytes(bytes);
```

What option should I set?

P.S. I use CheckStyle plugin in Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse-CS, you can set a checkmark in *Window ▶ Preferences ▶ Checkstyle ▶ Include Rule names in violation messages*. Then, for each violation, you can see the rule that caused it.

In your case, you have *Type Cast* enabled in both the [Whitespace After](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#WhitespaceAfter) and the [No Whitespace After](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#NoWhitespaceAfter) rules. You will want to uncheck *Type Cast* for "Whitespace After" in order to support your formatting.

Eclipse-CS will generate the XML for you, but if you must set it manually, you can do so by specifying the tokens to check (example shows how TYPECAST ist left out):

```xml
<module name="WhitespaceAfter">
    <property name="tokens" value="COMMA, SEMI"/>
</module>
```